# QML ListView greys out or removes text of element when adjacent element is selected

Tags: qt, user-interface, debugging, qml

So in testing my program, I discovered the strangest thing.

So, I have a ListView element with a custom C++ model, and a fairly simple delegate.  Each delegate is a MyButton class, which is simply a Text class(z:2), an Image class(z:1), and a MouseArea class.  That Image class is the background, and contains a translucent image which becomes opaque when MouseArea is onPressed().

Now the strange part.

When the ListView has 4 elements, it operates normally -except- when the user selects entry #3, then entry #2 or #1.

- When the selected entry goes from #3->#1, the text in entry #2 grays out as opposed to its normal white.
- When the selected entry goes from #3->#2, the text in entry #2 completely disappears.

After hours of testing and banging head against desk, I've uncovered a bit more:

- The opacity of MyButton or any of its children never changes.
- The color of MyButton's text element never changes
- The content of MyButton's test element never changes
- After offsetting the text partially outside of MyButton, this abnormal behavior only affects the text remaining inside the bounds of MyButton's Image child.
- The Z level of MyButton or any of its children never changes, though it appears as if MyButton's Image is being placed on top of its Text.
- Another image is never placed on top of a MyButton element.  If this was the case, when going from #3->#1 you would see the image of entry #2 become darker.
- When the ListView is scrolled, everything returns to normal.

When ListView contains 4 elements, below are the abnormalities:

- when #4->#1: #2 and #3 gray out
- when #4->#2: #2 disappears
- when #4->#3: #3 disappears
- when #3->#2: #2 disappears
- when #3->#1: #2 grays out

This is consistent to the image and text inside the MyButton class being re-ordered, placing the image a Z level above the text.  However the z levels are forced in the MyButton definition, and an onZChanged signal is never created when these events happen.

Below is the relevant code:

```
//MyButton:
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: button
    property string source: ""
    property string source_toggled: source
    property string button_text_alias: ""
    signal pressed
    width: button_image.sourceSize.width
    height: button_image.sourceSize.height
    property bool toggled: false

    Image{
        id: button_image
        z: 1
        source: toggled ? parent.source_toggled : parent.source

    }
    MyText{
        z: 2
        text_alias: button_text_alias
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: button_mouse
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: button.pressed()
    }
}


//ListView:
Component{
    id: p_button
    MyButton{
        source: picture_path + "bar.png"
        source_toggled: picture_path + "bar_selected.png"
        toggled: model.isCurrent
        onClicked: {
            profile_model.setCurrent(model.index)
        }
        button_text_alias: model.display
    }
}
ListView{
    id: p_list
    width: 623
    height: count*74 -1
    spacing: 1
    interactive: false
    model: p_model
    delegate: p_button
}
```

I can't think of -anything- that could cause this behavior.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this error by breaking up my delegate into:

```
Component{
    id: p_button
    Item{
        property bool toggled: model.isCurrent
        width: button_image.sourceSize.width
        height: button_image.sourceSize.height
        Image{
            id: button_image
            visible: !toggled
            source: picture_path + "bar.png"
        }
        Image{
            visible: toggled
            source: picture_path + "bar_selected.png"
        }
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: p_model.setCurrent(model.index)
        }
        MyText{
            text_alias: model.display
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```

So instead of swapping the source of an object, there are two objects which become visible/invisible based on a boolean value.  This prevented the issue, though I still don't know the cause.